# convert json array to var values in node.js express.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am trying go convert my json array in to simple (numbered)values.
getting them from database(.find), the problem is they are not converting with json.parse. am i doing something wrong?

```
 Voltage.find({},function (err, data) {
        var jsontext = data;
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(jsontext);
        res.json(parsedData);
        console.log(parsedData);
    });
```

ths is the console.log for the session, i was hoping for just: 333, 333, 333 etc.

```
[{"_id":"56f3c19a0298308405d60464","temp":333,"__v":0},{"_id":"56f3c1ee7ec57884068dcb2c","temp":333,"__v":0},{"_id":"56f3c4467ec57884068dcb2d","temp":333,"__v":0},{"_id":"56f3d80191a3c68c138bf04d","temp":337,"__v":0},{"_id":"56f3da3f06cefa781763fb21","temp":337,"__v":0}]
```

it is the temp values i am trying to get out to send to my front end only. i am using mongooose, express.js and node.js with a mongodb also.
thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is deselect them in the query:

```
 Voltage.find().select('-_id -__v').exec(function (err, data) {
        var jsontext = data;
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(jsontext);
        res.json(parsedData);
        console.log(parsedData);
    });
```

Read up on the select method [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js).

Comment: thats great, thanks.    that has narrowed it down a bit,i need to give the value if temo over as a var '333' . any idea how to do that? thanks again

Comment: i am getting back this message upon parsing   {undefined:1
{ temp: 333 },{ temp: 333 },{ temp: 333 },{ temp: 333 },{ temp: 333 },{ temp: 
  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token t
    at Object.parse (native)